# Programmatically Return Repository Type for Projects in TFS 2017

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I have a very large TFS Collection with many projects. It would take me a while to look through all the projects. Is there a command that I can use with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 that will return the type of repository; A command that will show me if my projects are TFVC or Git?

Thanks in advance,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) to get project with the specified id or name. When you include capabilities, the api will return the sourceControlType.

Since you are using TFS 2017, you need to set the **api-version=3.2**. Check the following example:

```
Get http://tfs2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/12999bb0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c58fb549c83f?includeCapabilities=true&api-version=3.2
```

You'll get the capabilities show as below:

```
"capabilities": {
        "processTemplate": {
            "templateName": "Scrum",
            "templateTypeId": "6b724908-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-768b5384da45"
        },
        "versioncontrol": {
            "sourceControlType": "Tfvc",
            "gitEnabled": "False",
            "tfvcEnabled": "True"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and get back to you with my results.

Comment: I am a newbie with REST API's, I'll be doing some research on how to run your command. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to get sourceControlType?